# How to look up multiple values at a time in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem. I have multiple excel files all with a few numbers in a list. I need to take those numbers in those lists and see if those values are in another excel sheet with over 570000 values. Then mark the next column over with a yes or no. As it stands I'm looking up over a hundred thousand values individually using control F. I was wondering if it is possible to look up the whole list at one time. This problem could also be phrases as searching for multiple unique values in a sheet at one time.

Any help? 
Thank you!

Edit: So if I'm trying to find 4 values in a list of 1000 values, is there anyway to get the cell next to each of those 4 values to say "yes"? Or is that impossible? The 4 values in this case would be the lists from other excel files.

Comment: A sampling of data from the source and target of the counts together with the expected results would go a long way towards getting focussed attention on your question.

Comment: You can edit questions to add missing details - please do that instead of (ab)using comments to do it. Take some care when formatting it though.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `COUNTIF` will show whether a value exists in another column no matter whether that column is on another worksheet or another workbook altogether.

Example: With both workbooks open, use this formula to find out if the value in A1 is in another workbook's (Other WB.xlsx) Sheet1 column B.

`=IF(COUNTIF([Other WB.xlsx]Sheet1!$B:$B, A1), "Yes", "No")`

If the two workbooks are open, you can `Alt+Tab` between to select column B from the other workbook while you are creating the formula. If you close the other workbook, the formula will reflect the full path of the closed workbook automatically like,

`=IF(COUNTIF('C:\Users\user\Documents\[Other WB.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B, A1), "Yes", "No")`

You can fill the formula down quickly by simply double-clicking on the small black square *drag handle* in the lower right of the the cell.

Comment: This has been so helpful! 2 questions though:
1. Where exactly do I plug in the formula?
2. For each value found in the original workbook, I have to mark the name of the file it was found in into the cell next to the value. Is that at all possible?

Comment: @SharvariJohari - 1. Any unused column to the right of the first value you want to look for. 2. If you change the formula to `=IF(COUNTIF([Other WB.xlsx]Sheet1!$B:$B, A1), "Other WB.xlsx", "")` it will fill in the WB name. Change the formula and put it into other unused columns to the right for other workbooks. A fully automated solution to compare every WB in a folder with every other WB in the same or a different folder would require VBA and it would be impossible to even contemplate starting something like that given the sparse information you have provided.